# What system tool is reporting this error and how to diagnose?

Tags: 12.04, security, bug-reporting, troubleshooting

In the last week, every time I turn my Ubuntu (12.04) machine on, and sporadically throughout operation (about every 1hr that I'm actively using it), I get the following popup from the system:

[image]

When I click the *Report problem...* button, it brings me to another dialog that asks me to put in my password:

> Please enter your password to access problem reports of system programs

I have yet to enter my password because I'm a little sketched out. What's going on here? What logs could I look in to start troubleshooting? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is Apport.

> Apport is an Error Reporting Service provided by Ubuntu to intercept
>   and analyse crashes and bugs as and when they occur. Crashes and Bugs
>   may sound like bad things, but actually most operating systems will
>   have several a day, and it doesn't mean your computer is broken, nor
>   does it necessarily stop working. As such, Apport can usually be
>   safely disabled, as it doesn't fix anything, it just tells developers
>   that something went wrong.<sup>1</sup>

Password is being asked for authentication purposes, that will take you to bugs. launchpad.net, if you don't have a Launchpad account all ready, you would have been asked to create an account, after you have logged in, you would have been asked to create a bug report.

For more information take a look  at [this](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-disable-apport-error-reporting-in-ubuntu#.UYektUrfPSQ)

Here are some of the log files kept in Ubuntu, and their usage.

> Linux Log files and usage
>
> - /var/log/messages : General log messages
> - /var/log/boot : System boot log
> - /var/log/debug : Debugging log messages
> - /var/log/auth.log : User login and authentication logs
> - /var/log/daemon.log : Running services such as squid, ntpd and others    log message to this file
> - /var/log/dmesg : Linux kernel ring buffer log
> - /var/log/dpkg.log : All binary package log includes package    installation and other information
> - /var/log/faillog : User failed login log file
> - /var/log/kern.log : Kernel log file
> - /var/log/lpr.log : Printer log file
> - /var/log/mail.* : All mail server message log files
> - /var/log/mysql.* : MySQL server log file
> - /var/log/user.log : All userlevel logs
> - /var/log/xorg.0.log : X.org log file
> - /var/log/apache2/* : Apache web server log files directory
> - /var/log/lighttpd/* : Lighttpd web server log files directory
> - /var/log/fsck/* : fsck command log
> - /var/log/apport.log : Application crash report / log file<sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Apport](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-disable-apport-error-reporting-in-ubuntu#.UYektUrfPSQ)</sup>

<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Source:[Log files in Ubuntu](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-gnome-system-log-viewer/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Mitch (+1) - I will most likely follow the recommended path, create a Launchpad account, and take advantage of this tool. However, I'd still like to know what is causing Apport to freak out in the first place (something is crashing or behaving badly). Is there anyway to diagnose this upfront, or do I need to go through Apport? If so, once I create this Launchpad account and the bug report is created, is there anything I can do (proactively) on my end to get to the root issue? Thanks again!

Comment: Anybody? Still trying to get to the root cause...

Comment: @TicketMonster - Have you looked at your system logs when the error occurs? You might find some clues there as to what has crashed/errored to cause the report.

Comment: Thanks @douggro (+1) - do you mean `/var/log/syslog` or something else?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the different log files, location, and usage.  Hope that will help you.